# Switch to alternative shorter text if text too long to fit

Tags: android, textview

I have single line TextView and I need to fit one of two variants into it

1. A longer preferred text
2. A shorter alternative text

If the longer text does not fit into the view (the point where ellipsize logic would kick in) I want to switch to the shorter alternative.

**Is there an elegant way to do this?**

The only way I can think of getting the paint from the view, [measuring the text](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#measureText(java.lang.String)) and comparing it to the view width (without padding).

For the sake of this question auto text resizing and ellipsize is not an option.

Comment: Using [getLineCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount%28%29) is an option to check? If there is more that one line you .setText(shorText)

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry, I have not been able to invest any time in this or solve it in any other way than I already described.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the `TextView` text with what is shown on the screen.

- `textView.getText()` -> The actual text of the `TextView`
- [`textView.getLayout().getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout#getText()) -> What is show on the screen.

```
fun TextView.isEllipsized() = layout?.text.toString() != text.toString()

if (textView.isEllipsized()) textView.text = "Short text."
```